# spinnaker buildRpm task is missing in 1.12.4

Tags: spinnaker

I gitclone the latest 1.12.4 release of spinnaker, and found that the buildRpm task is missing from all microservices.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

[Issue](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/4091) has been resolved

> Run ./gradlew -I gradle/init-publish.gradle buildRpm